# After extracting text with BeauitfulSoup, what can I do with that extracted data?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

My overall goal is isolate tags that contain a certain word in the text and have only those print to a text file.

So far, I have been able to extract particular the tag, in this case the  and get those to print to a text file.

My question is once I've got all the text in the  extracted, what can I do with it? I am having trouble figuring out a way to isolate a particular word and further trim the text down to only what I need.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.website.com'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

page = soup.findAll('title')

for element in page:    
    print element

file_name = raw_input("What do you want to name the file?> ")
text_file = open("/Users/user1/Projects/%s.txt" % file_name, "w")
text_file.write("%s" % page)
text_file.close()
```

What gets returned to me is:

```
$<title>food</title>
<title>ball</title>
<title>car</title>
<title>desk</title>
<title>blue food</title>
<title>green food</title>
<title>red ball</title>
```

How would I get it to only print results that include 'food'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the contents of an element using `.string`. If you only wish to include results with `food`, add a check for that:

```
for element in page:
    if 'food' in element.string:
        print element.string
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, that worked perfectly. So, by appending .string am I turning my results into a string? Also, is there way for it to return what I need regardless of it's case? For example if I need both 'Food' and 'food'.

Comment: Yes, it's the string between the start and end tags of that element.

Comment: @AlexRamadan : You could check for either `food` or `Food` separately (use the logical OR operator.) Alternately, if you want more flexibility, you can use a regular expression. (This will also let you do things like "match `food` only as a whole word", excluding matches for things like `foodstuff`.

Comment: @Simeon Visser, why is the script not printing only the results that I specify in the 'for element in page:' check to the .txt file? All the results are being printed to the txt file, not just the ones including 'food'.

Comment: It's now printing everything to the screen, not to a file. If you wish to save it in a file, you need to assign it to a variable and save the contents of that variable to a file. If we look at the code in your question, we're saving the variable `page` now and that's not the same as what I'm printing.

Answer (score 0):

For exemple if you want to extract the data from the page and put it in a CSV file, you can do like that :

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import csv

file_name = raw_input("What do you want to name the file?> ")
c = csv.writer(open("%s.csv" % (file_name), "a"),delimiter=";" ) # Open the CSV File and Write in

url = 'http://www.website.com'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

page = soup.findAll('title')

for element in page:    
    element = element.text.encode('utf-8')
    c.writerow([element])
```

You can use your CSV file in Excel or/and text editor software. Can be useful
My code is far away from the perfection but anyway, should work :)